# Reply-by-SMS with Google Voice

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, calls, google-voice, quick-responses

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running stock Android Jelly Bean 4.1.1. As you probably know, Jelly Bean has a new feature that allows you to "respond-by-SMS" to incoming phone calls. Unfortunately, this feature sends a text message from your "real" phone number instead of Google Voice. For those of us that use Google Voice full-time, and don't want to reveal our real phone numbers, and keep accurate messaging logs, this is undesirable behavior.

**Question**: Does anyone know if it's possible to get the respond-by-SMS feature to send from Google Voice instead of the built-in *Messaging* app?

The description of the feature in question is: "*When you miss a call, a new notification lets you return the call or reply by SMS with a single touch.*"

http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to 
Settings>Manage Applications>All Applications>

Go to your MMS.apk, and reset the defaults.

So long as you already have Google Voice installed on your phone, 
The next time you try to use this feature, it should ask you which one you want to use.

But IDK- No JB love on the HTC Sensation, *yet*.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.

Comment: The button to clear defaults is greyed out for the Messaging application.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple but amazingly effective workaround solution: [Any.Do for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo). Install it from Google Play.

How it works for me:

1. Decline incoming call
2. A missed call popup will appear from Any.Do. Choose the Send Text option
3. I think the first time you use it, you have to choose default app. Here's where you choose Google Voice and, bam, you are all set!

You can create custom default messages as well within Any.Do.

Hope this helps.